# Accessing 3d vector in a class c++

Tags: c++, class, vector

So here is my simplified code.

```
class Game
{
public:
    void helper(char c);
    vector<vector<vector<char>>> board(5, vector<vector<char>>(10, vector<char>(40)));
    Game();
};

void Game::helper(char c)
{
    int tempY = 0;
    int tempX = 0;
    int temp1 = 0;  
    if (board[temp1][tempY][tempX] != 'c')
    {
        board[temp1][tempY][tempX] = c;
    }
}
int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.helper('C');
    cout<<game.board[0][0][0]<<endl;
}
```

And then I got 2 errors on this line:

```
 if (board[temp1][tempY][tempX] != 'c')
```

1. error C3867: 'Game::board': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

2. error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Comment: Please, use curly brackets! `vector<vector<vector<char> > > board{ 5, vector<vector<char>>{10, vector<char>{40}} };`

Comment: Did you actually `#include <vector>`? Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: Pro tip: the errors at the top of the error list are the most important ones, because that's where things go wrong. You can't just ignore them and assume that they aren't the problem. You have to have gotten an error about your `board` initialization. It's not syntactically valid.

Comment: @knivil wow that worked!

Comment: @JamesRoot Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @knivil actually no..

Comment: Yes, it does remove the errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn up the warnings on your compiler.

```
vector<vector<vector<char>>> board(5, vector<vector<char>>(10, vector<char>(40)));
```

Is being translated to a function named `board` that returns a `vector<vector<vector<char>>>` and takes in invalid parameters.  You need to either use an in class initialization like

```
vector<vector<vector<char>>> board = vector<vector<vector<char>>>(5, vector<vector<char>>(10, vector<char>(40)));
```

Or create a constructor to initialize it.

All that being said you should not really nest vectors.  You can break the cache friendliness of the container as not all the nested vectors need to be next to each other in memory.  Typically what you do is use a 1d vector and fake the dimensions using math.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by someone else, this becomes a messy affair. It is better to use just a single contiguous memory array providing multi-dimensional accessors something like:

```
template <typename T>
class vector3d {
public:
    vector3d(size_t d1=0, size_t d2=0, size_t d3=0, T const & t=T()) :
        d1(d1), d2(d2), d3(d3), data(d1*d2*d3, t)
    {}

    T & operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) {
        return data[i*d2*d3 + j*d3 + k];
    }

    T const & operator()(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) const {
        return data[i*d2*d3 + j*d3 + k];
    }

private:
    size_t d1,d2,d3;
    std::vector<T> data;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to jump on the pile here, if you are amenable to using the Boost libraries, they have a [`multi_array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html) container that allows you to specify multi-dimensional arrays at run-time, so you get the nice `board[0][1][2]` interface, no nested `vector`s, and it's probably (haven't tested it) much faster than nested vectors.

For example, you would declare the board like so:

```
boost::multi_array<char, 3> board(boost::extents[5][10][40]);
```

You can then access it like this:

```
std::cout << board[0][1][2] << std::endl;
```

It is, however, probably a bit overkill for your purposes. Just wanted to let you know what's out there.

Comment: That's very helpful! One more question, if I want the boards have different height and width, is there any clever way to do so? For example, if I want to make the board that board[0] points to only have 10 rows and 10 cols instead of 40 rows and 10 cols? While others remain the same?

Comment: It's not possible to do that using multi_array. The underlying implementation is essentially the same as @Samer Tufail's, where the memory is in one contiguous block. If the third dimension is the only one that changes, you can have a `multi_array` of 2 dimensions and have the type be: `boost::multi_array<std::vector<char>, 2>`